# Merging tables after a data_file_directories change

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am currently stuck with missing data due to changes in the `data_file_directories` property.

This is a two-errors issue.

First, we had data in `/var/lib/cassandra/data` on a separated mount, and everything was fine.

After a cassandra upgrade (from 2.1 to 3.9), en error at configuration made us change the `data_file_directories` to `[/var/lib/cassandra/data1, /var/lib/cassandra/data2]`.

Seems like the error got unnoticed until we had the `/var` directory full. This made us discover the issue, and after some `nodetool removenode`, the cluster came back ... but with almost 2 months of missing data.

I would like to know if it is possible to get that `data1` and `data2` merged back into `data`.

Using `nodetool snapshot` is not an option as there we cannot go back to using `data1` and `data2` as data storage.

Thanks a lot for your help, whatever it is ;)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're saying that the old sstables were in different directories, then you updated the config to stop using those directories, and now with the updated config you no longer have access to the data that was written there, and you'd like to use it.

If you have the sstables available, you can copy them into the current `data_files_directories` and load them into the server with `nodetool refresh`.

Note, however, that this is not without risk - doing so may resurrect deleted data, and you must be sure you don't overwrite any files with the same generation (numerical ID in the filename).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jeff ... I tried it but it failed in the end. Not sure if I missed something.

Anyway, I was suggested to use `sstableloader`, and doing it seemed to to the trick.  Ifever it may help, I wrote a small script to try to take care of that all :

```
#!/bin/sh

DATADIRS=/var/lib/cassandra/data1
KEYSPACES="keyspace1 keyspace2"
NODES=192.168.10.21,192.168.10.22

backup=1
exec_cmd=""
test_mode=0

while [ "$#" != "0" ] ; do
    case ${1} in

    -nb|-nobackup|--nb|--no-backup)
        backup=0
        ;;

    -t|-test|--t|--test)
        exec_cmd=echo
        test_mode=1
        ;;

    -x)
        set -x
        ;;

    *)
        echo Unknown option ${1}, ignoring it.
        ;;

    esac

    shift
done

echo Started at : `date`

for keyspace in ${KEYSPACES} ; do

    for datadir in ${DATADIRS} ; do

        # Create backup dir if needed.

        if [ "${backup}" = "1" ] ; then
            ${exec_cmd} mkdir -p ~/cassandra/`basename ${datadir}`/${keyspace}
        fi

        # Get the list of tables.

        kstables=`find ${datadir}/${keyspace} -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d`

        # Now load tabled within active cassandra nodes.

        for d in ${kstables} ; do
            echo $d : `date`
            # Cannot use exec_cmd because of the pipe in the command.
            if [ "${test_mode}" = "1" ] ; then
                echo nice -n 10 sstableloader -d ${NODES} $d \> /dev/null
            else
                ${exec_cmd} nice -n 10 sstableloader -d ${NODES} $d >/dev/null
            fi

            # Backup table dir if needed

            if [ "${backup}" = "1" ] ; then
                ${exec_cmd} mv $d ~/cassandra/data1/${keyspace}
            else
                ${exec_cmd} rm -rf $d
            fi
        done
    done
done

echo Finished at : `date`
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Please note that, for `sstableloader` to work properly, the listen address and broadcast address of your cassandra.yaml must be identical.